# Launching a program (explorer extension) by keyboard hotkey?

Tags: c#, windows-shell, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

[Wrote an explorer extension](https://github.com/sergey900553/RandomNameChanger/blob/main/FileSystemScanner/FileInfoExtension.cs) using [sharpshell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell), that renames the highlighted files to a randomly generated name. But I just can't figure out how to make renaming work with the hotkeys shfit + f2.
The documentation contains Shortcut Keys, but as I understand it locally while the program is running, and I need to globally change the keyboard shortcuts in the windows environment.

```
namespace FileSystemScanner
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.AllFiles)]
    [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.Directory)]
    public class FileInfoExtension : SharpContextMenu
    {
        protected override bool CanShowMenu()
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
        {
            // create the menu strip.
            var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            var RenameFileItem = new ToolStripMenuItem
            {
                Text = "Случайное имя",
                Image = Properties.Resources.random,
                ShortcutKeys = Keys.Shift | Keys.F2
            };
            RenameFileItem.Click += (sender, args) => RenameFile();
            menu.Items.Add(RenameFileItem);
            return menu;
        }


        private void RenameFile()
        {
            foreach (var filePath in SelectedItemPaths)
            {
                string patchwitoutname = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                string exten = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                string oldname = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
                string newname = patchwitoutname + "\\" + GeneratedName() + exten;

                System.IO.Directory.Move(oldname, newname);
            }

        }

        private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

        public string GeneratedName()
        {
            string parameters = "abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
            int count = 13;
            string result = "";
            int lenght = parameters.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                result += parameters[rnd.Next(lenght)];
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using a Windows Forms; just needed to in designer comfirm a KeyDown action:

```
        private void yourForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "2")
                //your code here;
        }
```

For shift action, you need to use just e.Shift

Comment: Just to say, that is not combination CTRL+F2, that is combination CTRL+2 .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. Most likely I do not use Windows Forms. I added a link to the [github](https://github.com/sergey900553/RandomNameChanger/blob/main/FileSystemScanner/FileInfoExtension.cs).
My program is a shell extension that adds functionality when the right mouse button is pressed. [Screenshot of the program](https://imgur.com/LeBxJ1Y) - "Случайное имя" is a random name generation.

Comment: I'am missing to that CAN NOT do.  Beacuse, works does in explorer.exe, and all commands is sending just to explorer.exe. Maybe, create some background procces for waiting to press keys. You can use a my posted code with just this preloading: `this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.yourForm_KeyDown);`